# mysql substr not working like php

Tags: mysql, substr

Please help me resolve my query when using query - I just want to subtract a few characters and then use the % to find the matching LIKE:

```
select * from `providers` WHERE `name` LIKE SUBSTR('telin',1,4)%
```

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong, any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the source of `'telin'`? Does that come from a variable in PHP?

Comment: Yes, telin comes from php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `telin` is a column name rather than the literal string, it should be quoted in backticks.  If it is the literal string, then there is obviously no need to extract a substring from it.  I suspect however, that it was the result of a PHP variable you pasted here after echoing out the full query, then it is correctly single-quoted.

Anyway, you will need to concatenate the `SUBSTR()` result onto the `'%'` via `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT * FROM `providers` WHERE `name` LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTR(`telin`,1,4), '%');
```

But better would be to use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) to compare the first 4 characters of each:

```
SELECT * FROM `providers` WHERE LEFT(`name`, 4) = LEFT(`telin`,4);
```

Comment: Queries like this create a temporary table, so they don't scale very well for larger amounts of data. So long as you're only dealing with thousands of rows it will be fine.